# App crashes when sharedpreferencs called

Tags: sharedpreferences, crash-reports

I'm using android studio and I'm running into a problem here.
I'm trying to call a preference with shared preferences but when I get to that line the app crashes.
IF I'm reading the logcat right its because the shared preference is null.

```
public class counter extends AppCompatActivity {
    int timer1 = 0;
    String sec= "0";
    CountDownTimer cTimer = null;
    SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("cdtime", 0);
    int cdtime = mPrefs.getInt("cdtime", 300000);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_counter);

        cTimer = new CountDownTimer(cdtime, 1000){

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                TextView v = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                long min = ((millisUntilFinished/1000)/60);
                long secprime = ((millisUntilFinished-(min*60000))/1000);
                if(secprime>10){
                    sec = (""+secprime);
                }else {
                    sec = ("0" + secprime);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have included the logcat.
I have attempted to fix the problem by adding

```
if(cdtime=null){
    //action
}
```

but this throws a syntax error. What am i doing wrong?
NOTE: i have also tried moving the code to after the on.Create after the .super
and it throws the same error
The value `cdtime` is meant to set the time for the timer and i am trying to have this set in a separate activity for 'settings'.

#### logcat

> 32014-32014/com.example.user.medialert E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.user.medialert, PID: 32014
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.medialert/com.example.user.medialert.counter}:
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences
> android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2515)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
> at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:184)
> at com.example.user.medialert.counter.(counter.java:26)
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
> at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1650)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1079)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2505)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
> 09-25 18:29:14.221 647-647/com.example.user.medialert E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
> 09-25 18:29:14.221 647-647/com.example.user.medialert E/Zygote: v2
> 09-25 18:29:14.231 647-647/com.example.user.medialert E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution can be following:

**//change this**

```
SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("cdtime", 0);
```

**//with this**

```
SharedPreferences mPrefs = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Please let me know if it changes anything for you.

**EDIT** : After updating your new code should look somewhat like this -

```
public class counter extends AppCompatActivity {
    int timer1 = 0;
    String sec= "0";
    CountDownTimer cTimer = null;
    SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    int cdtime;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_counter);

        mPrefs = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        cdtime = mPrefs.getInt("cdtime", 300000);



        cTimer = new CountDownTimer(cdtime, 1000){

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                TextView v = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                long min = ((millisUntilFinished/1000)/60);
                long secprime = ((millisUntilFinished-(min*60000))/1000);
                if(secprime>10){
                    sec = (""+secprime);
                }else {
                    sec = ("0" + secprime);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason for this solution is the fact that you are not referring to any shared prefs file and getting a null point exception. If you are using just one shared prefs file in project then above solution should work.

Comment: if(cdtime == null){ //action } this is correct syntax for if statements checking equal to condition. **But in your case there is no need to do this. As the issue is in SharedPreferences initialization. Please try correcting that first.**

Comment: You should be editing prefs and initializing in **onCreate** not before that. You need to change that too.

Comment: I don't know of making the mode private is a good idea as like I mentioned, the values are being set in a different activity to this one. I'll change the code tonight but if you can explain why the removal of "cdtime" from the code, as this is the tag I need to edit? Thanks for your answers so far

Comment: You need not worry about setting mode private as it is not same as **private int** etc. Here is the actual description from google docs  **MODE_PRIVATE: File creation mode: the default mode, where the created file can only be accessed by the calling application (or all applications sharing the same user ID).** So you can see your whole application will access that shred prefs file. And I never said that you need to remove 'cdtime' . I just removed it from Shared Pref initialization code as it was **wrong format**

Comment: Please have a look at updated answer I have made changes in your code to give you an idea what I meant and how the code should actually look like. [To get better understanding of MODE_PRIVATE you can visit this link to official google docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_PRIVATE)

Comment: Adding the code mPrefs = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE); results in two red errors - 1) mPrefs cannot resolve symbol 2) getActivity cannot resolve symbol. This is placing them after the onCreate line. I'm wondering if the code needs to be different because it's android studio?

Comment: I was missing the SharedPrefernces = mPref line higher up, that has resolved one issue. However it is still red code on `getActivity().` saying cannot resolve method.

Comment: `public class counter extends AppCompatActivity {
    int timer1 = 0;
    String sec= "0";
    CountDownTimer cTimer = null;
    SharedPreferences mPrefs;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_counter);
        mPrefs = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int cdtime = mPrefs.getInt("cdtime", 300000);

        cTimer = new CountDownTimer(cdtime, 1000){`
SorryI havnt worked out how to format additional comments to look proper with code

Comment: Use **this.** instead of getActivity(). And let me know result.

Comment: You should define int cdtime before onCreate like mprefs. Check how I mentioned in code. That is more preferred way.

Comment: `public class counter extends AppCompatActivity {
    String sec= "0";
    CountDownTimer cTimer = null;
    SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    int cdtime;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_counter);
        mPrefs = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        cdtime = mPrefs.getInt("cdtime", 300000);

        cTimer = new CountDownTimer(cdtime, 1000){`

Have changed the code.
However cdtime always returns the default value of 300000 mills

Comment: cdTime returns default because you are **nowhere editing it/changing**. Do want to edit the value? **Is your initial Error solved now ?**

Comment: Initial error has been solved. I have started a different question in regards to the settings page not editing the value of cdtime.
Thanks for your help